# Firebase Firestore - The service is currently unavailable

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Exception has occurred.

> PlatformException (PlatformException(unavailable, The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff., {code: unavailable, message: The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff., nativeErrorMessage: Failed to get documents from server. (However, these documents may exist in the local cache. Run again without setting source to FirestoreSourceServer to retrieve the cached documents.), nativeErrorCode: 14}, null))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am having the same issue with cloud_firestore: ^3.1.15. Whenever I try to read the data from Firestore. However the real time database is fine and I can read the data from it.